# MAP Keyset not working- not recognizing keyword KeyType?

Tags: java, dictionary

I am trying to itreate over Keyset from a map but my program is not recognizing the keyword **KeyType**:

I am using the following code as mentioned in the Oracle Java Docs [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

```
for (KeyType key : outputMap.keySet())
    System.out.println(key);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the documentation is pseudo-code. Replace `KeyType` with the type you've stored in your `Map` as the key.

For example:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
  //..
}
```

Comment: ofcourse how could i missed it too bad. Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 1):

There is no reference type **KeyType** in java.
Try this example:

```
    Map<Integer, String> person = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    person.put(1, "Sohail");
    person.put(2, "Ahmad");
    person.put(3, "Wills");
    for(Integer serialNo : person.keySet()) 
        System.out.println("Key: "+serialNo+", Value: "+person.get(serialNo));
```

A Map is an object that maps keys to values. Here my key type is Integer and my value type is String as this example maps Serial no. to the person name.

You can also iterate on Map like this:

```
    Map<Integer, String> person = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    person.put(1, "Sohail");
    person.put(2, "Ahmad");
    person.put(3, "Wills");

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : person.entrySet()) 
        System.out.println("Key: "+entry.getKey()+", Value: "+entry.getValue());
```